# Share Cache among instances

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I have a application and I cache several data for it (.net cache). Normally this application runs using 2 or 3 instances.

Whenever a new instance is created to handle request, the memory usage become double. I am wondering if every new instance creates its own cache.

Is it true? if yes, is there a way to share the cache among the instances of the same application?

Thanks in advance for sharing the valuable knowledge!

EDIT :

Language c#
Please see below for example how we cache :

```
System.Web.HttpContext ctx
            = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
  ctx.Cache.Insert("siteViewModel", siteViewModel, null,
DateTime.Now.AddHours(Int32.Parse(siteViewModel.ApplicationSettings["dtoCacheDurationHours"])), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
                 System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Default, OnCachedItemRemoved);
```

Comment: We have similar requirements, but I'm not sure if it be appropriate to your situation, but we use a web service to cache data (with a security mechanism), there are other options like directly accessing a memcache server (which is behind our web service) or something similar, or keep it simple and use the application variable? Could you give more information on architecture and what environment it is used in?

Comment: What do you call an "instance"? Is your application running in webfarm mode?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played with this at all, but I understand that [AppFabric offers distributed caching features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383731%28v=azure.10%29.aspx). You may want to check out [some examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383406%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) [like this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff731039.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

First I need to tell that you can not use the cache among multiple instance.
You can also use the Windows azure caching system also to share the cache across the application and it is easily used using RESTful way.

Answer (score 0):

You can also evaluate Microsoft Velocity for your scenario. Velocity will provide you distributed and in-memory cache.

Link:
[Build Better Data-Driven Apps With Distributed Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd861287.aspx)